# arraylist remover doesnt work properly IOBE

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, int

I dont understand why im getting error IndexOutOfBoundsException. Code wortks fine with 2 removers but when i try to add third one compilier wont even start.

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
       // 1. Here im making list
        ArrayList  list = new ArrayList();

        //2. Putting values: «101», «102», «103», «104», «105».

        list.add( 101);  //0
        list.add( 102);
        list.add( 103);   //2
        list.add( 104);
        list.add( 105);      //4

        // 3. removing first, middle and the last one. here is main problem, i cant add list.remove(4) 
        list.remove(0);
        list.remove(2);
        list.remove(4);
       // 4. Using loop to get values on screen
        for ( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
       // 5. here im printing out size of arr
        System.out.println(list.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove an element of an arraylist, all the following elements will be shifted.

List content: 101, 102, 103, 104, 105
Calling remove(0)
List content: 102, 103, 104, 105
Calling remove(2)
List content: 102, 103, 105
Calling remove(4)
Exception! There isn't index 4 anymore.

Start with the highest index to work properly:

```
list.remove(4);
list.remove(2);
list.remove(0);
```

... or choose another way to remove the elements.

Comment: the answer is always so easy, but when you look for it. now i get it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code of [ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java). `remove` method is calling `rangeCheck` method which will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if you are trying to remove element with index higher than actual size.

Comment: so i have to put something like, if(list.size() < 5) list.add(0) ??

Comment: You really shouldn't remove items that way, rather remove elements by value with `list.remove(list.indexOf("105"));`